# What are the differences between day and night?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Other than stronger monsters, what else can I expect during the night? Are there treasures/shops/npcs/quests only available during nighttime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no special shops or treasures which only appear at night.

There are two other nighttime specific things, however.

1. Certain bounty hunts only appear at night.
2. Certain fish can only be caught at night.

When you accept a bounty wherein they only appear at night, you also have the option to wait until nightfall, at the Tipster, before tracking the bounty. This means you may have more of a challenge getting *to* the bounty.

Nighttime fishing is generally safe since Noctis is on a dock and fishing spends much time.

Comment: As an added note, some dungeons are only accessible at night.

Comment: Also worth noting with the fishing that there are 4 phases of the day, from daytime, night time but also dawn and dusk, which are the red semi-circle icons.